# Use different timezone for forms in django's admin site

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-timezone

I wonder if it is possible for django's admin site to accept two datetime fields of one model in two different timezones.

For example suppose I have a model like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    time_a = models.DateTimeField()
    time_b = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I use the django's admin site to add or edit an instance of A, I wish I may fill field time_a in UTC+8, and time_b in UTC+9. i.e. If I fill time_a with 08:00 and time_b with 09:00, they are the same in UTC.

I know that I may override A's save() method and handle inputs manually with doing the timedelta calculation myself, but I wonder if there is a more convenient way or more proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could extend the django's DateTimeField ([https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L1332](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1332)), changing its **init** to accept one more argument `default_timezone` and alter to_python method (which is inherited from DateField [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__) init.py#L1257) to use that default_timezone.

I haven't tested that

EDIT: What you see as a bold init in fact is a dunder init (init with two underscores before and two underscores after). I just don't realized how to disable markup here in stackoverflow.